# Running GWT 2.4 Tests With JUnitCore

Tags: testing, gwt

I have several GWTTestCases in my test suite, and I'm currently using a homegrown testing script which is written in Java that runs tests as follows:

```
for(Class<?> testClass : allTestClasses) {
    final JUnitCore core = new JUnitCore();
    final Result result = core.run(testClass);
}
```

Now, the first GWT test will pass and all subsequent tests will fail.  It doesn't matter which test runs first, and I can run the tests successfully from the command line.

Looking through the logs, the specific error is typically like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deepthought.test.JUnit:package.GwtTestCaseClass.testMethod: could not instantiate the requested class
```

I think it has something to do with GWTTestCase static state, but am unsure.  If I do one run where I pass all the testClasses to the core, they all pass, and then subsequently any individual test will pass.

My guess is that gwt compiles and caches the tests you are running, and then stores them based on the module.  But in this case, the compiler misses my other test cases, because it doesn't see a dependency to them.  Then for the next test, it comes back to the cache, hits it and fails to find the test I want.

Any thoughts on a workaround, other than just passing all the tests in at once?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I discovered is to first add all the GWTTestCase classes to a GWTTestSuite, which you can then throw away.  You don't incur the cost of compilation at this point, but it somehow makes GWT aware of all the test cases, and so when you compile the first one...they all get compiled.

If you ask me, this is a GWT bug.